# XSLT- How to insert tag attribute based upon informations from another XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I have one XML file named "fr_Cussac.xm" which looks like:

```
<TEI xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0 file:fr_Cussac.xsd"
 xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"><TEI xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0 file:fr_Cussac.xsd"
 xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
    <text>
        <body>
            <p>
                <s>
                    <w lemma="boucle" type="NOM">Boucle</w>
                    <w lemma="de" type="PRP">de</w>
                    <w lemma="randonner" type="VER:pres">randonnée</w>
                    <w lemma="pouvoir" type="VER:ppre">pouvant</w>
                    <w lemma="se" type="PRO:PER">se</w>
                    <w lemma="faire" type="VER:infi">faire</w>
                    <w lemma="à" type="PRP">à</w>
                    <w lemma="pied" type="NOM">pieds</w>
                    <w lemma="ou" type="KON">ou</w>
                    <w lemma="à" type="PRP">à</w>
                    <w lemma="unknown" type="NAM">VTT</w>
                    <w lemma="." type="SENT">.</w>
                </s>
                <s>
                    <w lemma="elle" type="PRO:PER">Elle</w>
                    <phr type="motion">
                        <w lemma="partir" type="VER:pres">part</w>
                        <w lemma="de" type="PRP">de</w>
                         <w lemma="unknown" type="NAM">Cussac</w>
                         <offset type="inclusion">
                            <w lemma="en" type="PRP">en</w>
                         </offset>
                         <w lemma="unknown" type="NAM">Haute-Vienne</w>
                        <w lemma="," type="PUN">,</w>
                        <w lemma="sur" type="PRP">sur</w>
                            <term type="N">
                                <w lemma="le" type="DET:ART">la</w>
                                <w lemma="place" type="NOM">place</w>
                            </term>
                        <offset type="direction" subtype="initial">
                            <w lemma="de" type="PRP">de</w>
                        </offset>
                        <geogName type="S" subtype="CH">
                            <geogFeat>
                                <w lemma="le" type="DET:ART">l'</w>
                                <w lemma="église" type="NOM">église</w>
                            </geogFeat>
                        </geogName>
                    </phr>
                    <w lemma="puis" type="ADV">puis</w>
                    <phr type="motion">
                        <w lemma="descendre" type="VER:pres">descend</w>
                        <w lemma="vers" type="PRP">vers</w>
                        <w lemma="le" type="DET:ART">la</w>
                        <w lemma="station" type="NOM">station</w>
                        <w lemma="de" type="PRP">d'</w>
                        <geogFeat>
                            <w lemma="épuration" type="NOM">épuration</w>
                        </geogFeat>
                    </phr>
                    <phr type="motion">
                        <w lemma="emprunter" type="VER:pres">empruntant</w>
                        <geogName type="R" subtype="TRL">
                            <geogFeat>
                                <w lemma="le" type="DET:ART">le</w>
                                <w lemma="sentier" type="NOM">sentier</w>
                                <w lemma="du" type="PREPDET">du</w>
                                <w lemma="parcours" type="NOM">parcours</w>
                                <w lemma="sportif" type="A">sportif</w>
                            </geogFeat>
                        </geogName>
                    </phr>
                    <w lemma="derrière" type="PRP">derrière</w>
                    <geogName type="S" subtype="CH">
                        <geogFeat>
                            <w lemma="le" type="DET:ART">l'</w>
                            <w lemma="église" type="NOM">église</w>
                        </geogFeat>
                    </geogName>
                    <w lemma="." type="SENT">.</w>
                </s>
    <text>
        <body>
            <p>
                <s>
                    <w lemma="boucle" type="NOM">Boucle</w>
                    <w lemma="de" type="PRP">de</w>
                    <w lemma="randonner" type="VER:pres">randonnée</w>
                    <w lemma="pouvoir" type="VER:ppre">pouvant</w>
                    <w lemma="se" type="PRO:PER">se</w>
                    <w lemma="faire" type="VER:infi">faire</w>
                    <w lemma="à" type="PRP">à</w>
                    <w lemma="pied" type="NOM">pieds</w>
                    <w lemma="ou" type="KON">ou</w>
                    <w lemma="à" type="PRP">à</w>
                    <w lemma="unknown" type="NAM">VTT</w>
                    <w lemma="." type="SENT">.</w>
                </s>
                <s>
                    <w lemma="elle" type="PRO:PER">Elle</w>
                    <phr type="motion">
                        <w lemma="partir" type="VER:pres">part</w>
                        <w lemma="de" type="PRP">de</w>
                         <w lemma="unknown" type="NAM">Cussac</w>
                         <offset type="inclusion">
                            <w lemma="en" type="PRP">en</w>
                         </offset>
                         <w lemma="unknown" type="NAM">Haute-Vienne</w>
                        <w lemma="," type="PUN">,</w>
                        <w lemma="sur" type="PRP">sur</w>
                            <term type="N">
                                <w lemma="le" type="DET:ART">la</w>
                                <w lemma="place" type="NOM">place</w>
                            </term>
                        <offset type="direction" subtype="initial">
                            <w lemma="de" type="PRP">de</w>
                        </offset>
                        <geogName type="S" subtype="CH">
                            <geogFeat>
                                <w lemma="le" type="DET:ART">l'</w>
                                <w lemma="église" type="NOM">église</w>
                            </geogFeat>
                        </geogName>
                    </phr>
                    <w lemma="puis" type="ADV">puis</w>
                    <phr type="motion">
                        <w lemma="descendre" type="VER:pres">descend</w>
                        <w lemma="vers" type="PRP">vers</w>
                        <w lemma="le" type="DET:ART">la</w>
                        <w lemma="station" type="NOM">station</w>
                        <w lemma="de" type="PRP">d'</w>
                        <geogFeat>
                            <w lemma="épuration" type="NOM">épuration</w>
                        </geogFeat>
                    </phr>
                    <phr type="motion">
                        <w lemma="emprunter" type="VER:pres">empruntant</w>
                        <geogName type="R" subtype="TRL">
                            <geogFeat>
                                <w lemma="le" type="DET:ART">le</w>
                                <w lemma="sentier" type="NOM">sentier</w>
                                <w lemma="du" type="PREPDET">du</w>
                                <w lemma="parcours" type="NOM">parcours</w>
                                <w lemma="sportif" type="A">sportif</w>
                            </geogFeat>
                        </geogName>
                    </phr>
                    <w lemma="derrière" type="PRP">derrière</w>
                    <geogName type="S" subtype="CH">
                        <geogFeat>
                            <w lemma="le" type="DET:ART">l'</w>
                            <w lemma="église" type="NOM">église</w>
                        </geogFeat>
                    </geogName>
                    <w lemma="." type="SENT">.</w>
                    <w type="NAM">Boubon</w>
                </s>
       </p>
        </body>
    </text>
</TEI>
```

and another file named "fr_Cussac-coord-entites.xml" which looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<geolocalisation  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="localisation-2.xsd">
   <entite_spatiale id="ene.0" lng="0.8519611512411495" lat="45.7055740420633" alt="349.0322265625">Cussac</entite_spatiale>
   <entite_spatiale id="ene.1" lng="0.859333" lat="45.712939" alt="280.5089111328125">Monnerie</entite_spatiale>
   <entite_spatiale id="ene.2" lng="0.857138" lat="45.687754" alt="376.1028137207031">Liades</entite_spatiale>
   <entite_spatiale id="ene.3" lng="0.8256439978387133" lat="45.67243279742165" alt="415.4050903320312">Boubon</entite_spatiale>
   <entite_spatiale id="ene.4" lng="0.8219117961938217" lat="45.67606269511061" alt="420.0135498046875">Villajou</entite_spatiale>
   <entite_spatiale id="ene.5" lng="0.8150905847864954" lat="45.68782102152895" alt="380.9435729980469">Puymoroux</entite_spatiale>
   <entite_spatiale id="ene.6" lng="0.8519611512411495" lat="45.7055740420633" alt="349.0322265625">Cussac</entite_spatiale>
   <entite_spatiale id="ene.7" lng="0.8519611512411495" lat="45.7055740420633" alt="349.0322265625">Cussac</entite_spatiale>
</geolocalisation>
```

I would like to iterate through the first file and, for each w tag with a "type" attribute equal to "NAM", find a match in the second file and surround it with placeName tags with the corresponding id.
(Ex: Match `<w>Cussac</w> with <entite_spatial>Cussac</entite_spatial>` and get the id)

Expected output:

```
  <TEI xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0 file:fr_Cussac.xsd"
 xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"><TEI xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0 file:fr_Cussac.xsd"
 xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
    <text>
        <body>
            <p>
                <s>
                    <w lemma="boucle" type="NOM">Boucle</w>
                    <w lemma="de" type="PRP">de</w>
                    <w lemma="randonner" type="VER:pres">randonnée</w>
                    <w lemma="pouvoir" type="VER:ppre">pouvant</w>
                    <w lemma="se" type="PRO:PER">se</w>
                    <w lemma="faire" type="VER:infi">faire</w>
                    <w lemma="à" type="PRP">à</w>
                    <w lemma="pied" type="NOM">pieds</w>
                    <w lemma="ou" type="KON">ou</w>
                    <w lemma="à" type="PRP">à</w>
                    <w lemma="unknown" type="NAM">VTT</w>
                    <w lemma="." type="SENT">.</w>
                </s>
                <s>
                    <w lemma="elle" type="PRO:PER">Elle</w>
                    <phr type="motion">
                        <w lemma="partir" type="VER:pres">part</w>
                        <w lemma="de" type="PRP">de</w>
                        <placeName id="ene.0"><!-- EXAMPLE HERE-->
                           <w lemma="unknown" type="NAM">Cussac</w>
                        </placeName>
                         <offset type="inclusion">
                            <w lemma="en" type="PRP">en</w>
                         </offset>
                         <w lemma="unknown" type="NAM">Haute-Vienne</w>
                        <w lemma="," type="PUN">,</w>
                        <w lemma="sur" type="PRP">sur</w>
                            <term type="N">
                                <w lemma="le" type="DET:ART">la</w>
                                <w lemma="place" type="NOM">place</w>
                            </term>
                        <offset type="direction" subtype="initial">
                            <w lemma="de" type="PRP">de</w>
                        </offset>
                        <geogName type="S" subtype="CH">
                            <geogFeat>
                                <w lemma="le" type="DET:ART">l'</w>
                                <w lemma="église" type="NOM">église</w>
                            </geogFeat>
                        </geogName>
                    </phr>
                    <w lemma="puis" type="ADV">puis</w>
                    <phr type="motion">
                        <w lemma="descendre" type="VER:pres">descend</w>
                        <w lemma="vers" type="PRP">vers</w>
                        <w lemma="le" type="DET:ART">la</w>
                        <w lemma="station" type="NOM">station</w>
                        <w lemma="de" type="PRP">d'</w>
                        <geogFeat>
                            <w lemma="épuration" type="NOM">épuration</w>
                        </geogFeat>
                    </phr>
                    <phr type="motion">
                        <w lemma="emprunter" type="VER:pres">empruntant</w>
                        <geogName type="R" subtype="TRL">
                            <geogFeat>
                                <w lemma="le" type="DET:ART">le</w>
                                <w lemma="sentier" type="NOM">sentier</w>
                                <w lemma="du" type="PREPDET">du</w>
                                <w lemma="parcours" type="NOM">parcours</w>
                                <w lemma="sportif" type="A">sportif</w>
                            </geogFeat>
                        </geogName>
                    </phr>
                    <w lemma="derrière" type="PRP">derrière</w>
                    <geogName type="S" subtype="CH">
                        <geogFeat>
                            <w lemma="le" type="DET:ART">l'</w>
                            <w lemma="église" type="NOM">église</w>
                        </geogFeat>
                    </geogName>
                    <w lemma="." type="SENT">.</w>
                </s>
    <text>
        <body>
            <p>
                <s>
                    <w lemma="boucle" type="NOM">Boucle</w>
                    <w lemma="de" type="PRP">de</w>
                    <w lemma="randonner" type="VER:pres">randonnée</w>
                    <w lemma="pouvoir" type="VER:ppre">pouvant</w>
                    <w lemma="se" type="PRO:PER">se</w>
                    <w lemma="faire" type="VER:infi">faire</w>
                    <w lemma="à" type="PRP">à</w>
                    <w lemma="pied" type="NOM">pieds</w>
                    <w lemma="ou" type="KON">ou</w>
                    <w lemma="à" type="PRP">à</w>
                    <w lemma="unknown" type="NAM">VTT</w>
                    <w lemma="." type="SENT">.</w>
                </s>
                <s>
                    <w lemma="elle" type="PRO:PER">Elle</w>
                    <phr type="motion">
                        <w lemma="partir" type="VER:pres">part</w>
                        <w lemma="de" type="PRP">de</w>
                        <placeName id="ene.0"><!--EXAMPLE HERE-->
                           <w lemma="unknown" type="NAM">Cussac</w>
                        </placeName>
                         <offset type="inclusion">
                            <w lemma="en" type="PRP">en</w>
                         </offset>
                         <w lemma="unknown" type="NAM">Haute-Vienne</w>
                        <w lemma="," type="PUN">,</w>
                        <w lemma="sur" type="PRP">sur</w>
                            <term type="N">
                                <w lemma="le" type="DET:ART">la</w>
                                <w lemma="place" type="NOM">place</w>
                            </term>
                        <offset type="direction" subtype="initial">
                            <w lemma="de" type="PRP">de</w>
                        </offset>
                        <geogName type="S" subtype="CH">
                            <geogFeat>
                                <w lemma="le" type="DET:ART">l'</w>
                                <w lemma="église" type="NOM">église</w>
                            </geogFeat>
                        </geogName>
                    </phr>
                    <w lemma="puis" type="ADV">puis</w>
                    <phr type="motion">
                        <w lemma="descendre" type="VER:pres">descend</w>
                        <w lemma="vers" type="PRP">vers</w>
                        <w lemma="le" type="DET:ART">la</w>
                        <w lemma="station" type="NOM">station</w>
                        <w lemma="de" type="PRP">d'</w>
                        <geogFeat>
                            <w lemma="épuration" type="NOM">épuration</w>
                        </geogFeat>
                    </phr>
                    <phr type="motion">
                        <w lemma="emprunter" type="VER:pres">empruntant</w>
                        <geogName type="R" subtype="TRL">
                            <geogFeat>
                                <w lemma="le" type="DET:ART">le</w>
                                <w lemma="sentier" type="NOM">sentier</w>
                                <w lemma="du" type="PREPDET">du</w>
                                <w lemma="parcours" type="NOM">parcours</w>
                                <w lemma="sportif" type="A">sportif</w>
                            </geogFeat>
                        </geogName>
                    </phr>
                    <w lemma="derrière" type="PRP">derrière</w>
                    <geogName type="S" subtype="CH">
                        <geogFeat>
                            <w lemma="le" type="DET:ART">l'</w>
                            <w lemma="église" type="NOM">église</w>
                        </geogFeat>
                    </geogName>
                    <w lemma="." type="SENT">.</w>
                    <placeName id="ene.5"><!-- EXAMPLE HERE-->
                      <w type="NAM">Boubon</w>
                    </placeName>
                </s>
       </p>
        </body>
    </text>
</TEI>
```

I have a draft of xslt that looks like this but I am absolutely not sure:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0" xmlns:tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
    <xsl:output method=" xml " indent=" yes "/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="tei:p tei:w tei:s tei:body tei:text"/>
    <xsl:variable name="positions" select="document('fr_Cussac-coord-entites.xml')"/>
    <xsl:template match="tei:TEI">
        <TEI>
            <xsl:apply-templates></xsl:apply-templates>
        </TEI>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="tei:text">
        <text>
            <xsl:apply-templates></xsl:apply-templates>
        </text>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="tei:body"> 
        <body>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </body>
     </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="tei:p">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="tei:s">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="tei:w[@type = 'NAM']">
        <placeName>
            <w>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </w>
        </placeName>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="tei:w[not(@type = 'NAM')]">
        <w lemma= "{@lemma}" type="{@type}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </w>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="tei:phr">
        <phr>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </phr>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="tei:geogFeat">
        <geoFeat>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </geoFeat>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'm new to xslt and I have no idea how to go about it that's why I'm asking for your help. Thanking for your reading and to those who will respond

Answer (score 0):

Declare a key `<xsl:key name="ref" match="entite_spatiale" use="."/>` as a top-level element in the XSLT code, then write the template

```
<xsl:template match="tei:w[@type = 'NAM'][key('ref', ., $positions)]">
    <placeName xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" id="{key('ref', ., $positions)/@id}>
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </placeName>
</xsl:template>
```

I would handle the rest by the identity transformation, unless you want to change/transform other elements as well.

Comment: You literally saved my day, thank you very much! Normally placeName should belong to the TEI namespace

Comment: @Boubourazi, I have edited the code sample to put the new placeName element into the TEI namespace.